# How to add the textbox name as parameter in a sub

Tags: sql, vb.net, .net-4.0

I have created a button to add the fields in a a textbox and I wanted to pass the textbox name as parameter in a sub,which inturn inserts into the database..How can i do it..pls find my code for reference below in vb.net

The code for inserting the values in database

```
Sub Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim addedButton As Button = sender
        Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
        Dim insertdata As String

        addedButton.Text = "Added"
        adduser = True
        addedButton.Enabled = True

        If (cname.Value = " " Or cid.Value = " " Or cadd.Value = " " Or cph.Value = " " Or fax.Value = " " Or cmail.Value = " ") Then
            Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: Null values not allowed for " _
                & "Client ID, Name"
            Message.Style("color") = "red"
            BindGrid()
        Else
            Message.InnerHtml = "<b>Client Record has been added</b><br/>"     
        End If

        insertdata = "INSERT INTO dbo.ClientInfo([Client Name],[Client ID],[Client Address],[Client Telephone No],[Client Fax No],[Client E-mail]) values("
        insertdata = insertdata + " ' " + cname.Value + " '," + cid.Value + ",' " + cadd.Value + " '," + cph.Value + "," + fax.Value + "," + cmail.Value
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(insertdata, sqlcon)



        Try
            sqlcmd.Connection.Open()
            Dim addcount As Integer = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If addcount > 0 Then
                Message.InnerHtml = "Record successfully Added"
            Else
                Message.InnerHtml = "Record not added"
            End If

        Catch ex As SqlException

            If ex.Number = 2627 Then
                Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: A record already exists with " _
                   & "the same primary key"
            End If
        Finally
            sqlcmd.Connection.Close()
            BindGrid()
        End Try      
    End Sub


    <asp:Button id="Button1"
                   Text="Add data"
                   OnClick="Add_Click"
                   runat="server"/><br />

  Name:<input type ="text" id="cname" name="" value="" runat="server"/><br />
              ID: <input type = "text" id="cid" name="txtclientid" value="" runat="server"/><br />
              Address:<input type="text" id="cadd" name="txtclientadd" value="" runat="server"/><br />
              Phone No:<input type="text" id="cph" name="txtno" value="" runat="server" /><br />
              Fax No:<input type="text" id="fax" name="faxno" value="" runat="server"/><br />
              E-mail:<input type="text" id="cmail" name="mail" value="" runat="server"/><br />
              <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" /><br />
```

Comment: Holy Sql Injection vulnerability, Batman.

Comment: your query is not advisable, here's walk-through to [avoid sql injection](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0360__ADO.net-Database/AvoidSQLinjection.htm)

Comment: Look into the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but closer to what you should be doing:

```vb
Public Sub InsertClientInfo(ByVal ClientName As String, ByVal ClientID As Integer, ByVal ClientAddress As String, ByVal ClientPhone As String, ByVal ClientFax As String, ByVal ClientEmail As String)

    Dim sql As String = _
      "INSERT INTO ClientInfo (" & _
          "[Client Name],[Client ID],[Client Address],[Client Telephone No],[Client Fax No],[Client E-mail]" & _
     ") VALUES (" & _
          "@ClientName,  @ClientID,  @ClientAddress,   @ClientPhone,         @ClientFax,     @ClientEmail)"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        'I had to guess at the column types and lengths here. Adjust accordingly
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ClientName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ClientID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = ClientAddress
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientPhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = ClientPhone
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientFax", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = ClientFax
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ClientEmail

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note that I had to guess at data types and sizes. You need to fix that to make your actual table definitions. Call it like this:

```
InsertClientInfo(textname.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textclientid.Text), txtclientadd.Text, txtno.Text, faxno.Text, mail.Text)
```

Comment: I have used the code ..but am not able to insert the values inside the table ..pls find my code above

Comment: @balaji No spaces allowed in the parameter names

Comment: And the "-" in "E-mail" will be treated like a subtraction operator.

Comment: Lastly, You should call `sqlcmd.Connection.Open()` inside the Try block, and you **must** call `sqlcmd.Connection.Close()` in a Finally block, or you risk leaving connections open and eventually locking out your database.

Comment: I have made the changes as u said..But still I can enter the fields in the textbox,but the values are not being entered into table..please find my edited code above for reference..thanks..could you kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

To pass the TEXTBOX name to any sub do as follows,

```
Sub SomeSubName(ThisTextboxName as string)
  'your code here
End Sub
```

or to a function

```
Function SomeFunctionName(ThisTextBoxName as String) As Boolean
  'your code here
End Function
```

Where...
SomeSubName and SomeFunctionName are the names of your sub or function
ThisTextBoxName is the variable name of the STRING data which is the actual textbox name

So if your textbox is named txtPhone Then you would pass it as....

SomeSubName(txtPhone.Name)

or

Dim Test as Boolean

Test = SomeFunctionName(txtPhone.Name)

Comment: Curious why you didn't like my edit? All I did was fix code formatting. Per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: No your edit didn't seem to edit much maybe just one or two small typos which I thought i had fixed but upon second checking i missed one out. And I think its best I decide whats good for me and whats not. Thank You.